# Video splitting in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, video

I need to develop a video editor in as3. Where, I need to split a long video into small clips and save them. Is there way to do it?

Comment: Short answer is yes. Long answer is what have you tried?

Comment: I found ffmpeg library and tried to use it AIR using NativeProcess. But I am getting "NativeProcess not supported".

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this: [FLVSlicer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=955) from bytearray.org? This could be good start.

Answer (score 0):

Also check this fast Alchemy FLV encoder: http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/updated-flv-encoder-alchem/